# I am trying to input a sliced string into an array however, my array is being filled with 0s

Tags: arrays, vb.net, file

I am trying to create code that randomly generates 3 sets of numbers (they all have different ranges) and concatenate them together into a single line, then the second part of my code reads the 2nd set of number from the text file and puts them into a string. However it looks like there is something wrong with my code that prevents the middle number string from being input into the array as when I output the array, it's full of 0s.

The entire code is as follows:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim r1, r2, r3, counter, counter1, counter2, sep As Integer
    Dim line As String
    Dim middleline(20)
    counter2 = 1
    sep = 0
    line = ""
    FileSystem.FileOpen(1, "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\binarysearch.txt", OpenMode.Output, OpenAccess.Write)
    For counter = 1 To 20
        If Rnd() = 0.21 Then
            r1 = -1
        Else
            Do
                r1 = Rnd() * 100
            Loop Until r1 <= 20
        End If
        Do
            r2 = Rnd() * 100
        Loop Until r2 >= 10 AndAlso r2 <= 50
        If Rnd() = 0.21 Then
            r3 = -1
        Else
            Do
                r3 = Rnd() * 100
            Loop Until r3 <= 20
        End If
        line = r1 & ":" & r2 & ":" & r3
        FileSystem.WriteLine(1, line)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Generated successfully.")
    FileSystem.FileClose(1)
    FileSystem.FileOpen(1, "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\binarysearch.txt", OpenMode.Input)
    For counter = 1 To 20
        middleline(counter) = 0
    Next

    For counter = 1 To 20
        line = FileSystem.LineInput(1)
        For counter1 = 1 To Len(line)
            If Mid(line, counter1, 1) = ":" Then
                sep = sep + 1
            ElseIf sep = 1 Then
                middleline(counter2) = (middleline(counter2) & Mid(line, counter1, 1))
                counter2 = counter2 + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    For counter = 1 To 20
        Console.WriteLine(middleline(counter))
    Next
End Sub
End Module
```

I feel like there is an issue specifically with this part of the code that may be the culprit, however I can't find the issue as everything looks okay (a bit inefficient but ill fix it afterwards).

```
 For counter = 1 To 20
        line = FileSystem.LineInput(1)
        For counter1 = 1 To Len(line)
            If Mid(line, counter1, 1) = ":" Then
                sep = sep + 1
            ElseIf sep = 1 Then
                middleline(counter2) = (middleline(counter2) & Mid(line, counter1, 1))
                counter2 = counter2 + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: While not direct answers, a couple initial thoughts for you.  1) Read up on Set Option Strict.  You're doing a heap of implied type casts that may be contributing.  Next, the Mid function, really only there for backwards compatablity.  String.SubString() nowdays.  Aside, you probably need to do some debugging, a breakpoint maybe so you can step through the code and inspect what is happening at each point.  Then maybe update your question with a clear explanation of exactly what is happening and how it's failing

Comment: To the actual question, would say you might be able to do something with String.Split() which will chop up strings on a delimiter into an array.

Comment: I'd also change how you are generating random numbers. `If Rnd() = 0.21` is essentially never going to be true. Instead of casting floating point random numbers to integers, use a method intended to generate integers, i.e., `Random.Next(below_this)`

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not finding the mistake in your code, but it was actually easier to just rewrite it using better tools for the job. The language comes with features to make your life easier, you might as well use them.

```
Module Program
    Sub Main()
        Dim rand = New Random()
        Dim r1, r2, r3 As Integer
        Dim line As String = ""
        Dim middles As New List(Of String)(20)

        ' Generate and write 20 lines of random numbers
        Dim fwrite = New System.IO.StreamWriter("binarysearch.txt")
        For counter = 1 To 20
            ' r1 is a random number between -1 and 20 (inclusive)
            r1 = rand.Next(-1, 21)
            ' r2 is a random number between 10 and 50
            r2 = rand.Next(10, 51)
            ' r3 is a random number between -1 and 20
            r3 = rand.Next(-1, 21)
            line = $"{r1}:{r2}:{r3}"
            fwrite.WriteLine(line)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Generated successfully.")
        fwrite.Close()

        ' Read 20 lines, extract middle string
        Dim fread = New System.IO.StreamReader("binarysearch.txt")
        For counter = 1 To 20
            line = fread.ReadLine()
            Dim middle = line.Split(":"c)(1)
            middles.Add(middle)
        Next
        fread.Close()

        ' Write the middle strings we extracted
        For Each middle In middles
            Console.WriteLine(middle)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```